# Renewing Azerbaijani temporary residence on a new passport

Tags: passports, azerbaijan, visa-renewals, yemeni-citizens

I am a Yemeni Citizen living and working in Azerbaijan. My passport will expire soon, and I'm concerned that I won't be able to renew my temporary residency.

We don't have a Yemeni Embassy in Azerbaijan, so I have contacted my Embassy in Malaysia as I have some connections there. They said that I can send the required documents and get a new passport; they will send it by DHL.

Is it fine if I do that? My new passport won't have any stamps on it, and I am worried about difficulties renewing my Azerbaijani residence when they see this. Will I be asked to leave and re-enter the country?

Comment: If the Embassy in Malaysia says they'll renew your passport by DHL, I see no particular reason to doubt them. What is your concern?

Comment: When I get my new passport to Azerbaijan, and then go to renew my temporary residency, I will have to submit the new passport..  I am worried they ask about entry stamp or say i must go out and come back .

Comment: Many countries will allow you to keep your existing passport (though obviously invalidated, for instance with a corner cut, or a whole punched through the whole passport) so any existing visas or stamps are still available. This may vary from country to country, and you usually have to explicitly request it, though. Check with your connections at the embassy whether that is possible.

Comment: My embassy would allow me to keep my old passport , all my concerns is will Azerbaijan accept my new passport that I got by DHL or they would require me to go out of country and then enter again with new passport

Comment: This might be better on Expats.

Comment: Hi @al-yemenal-saeed, I asked my friend who works as a data engineer for Az. State Migration Service. He'll ask his colleagues and then I'll post an answer here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my acquittances in the State Migration Service of Azerbaijan, I've been told that you can apply with your current residence permit, the old passport and the new passport. They will exchange your current residence permit to a newer one without any fees. The validity period of the new residence permit will be the same as your current residence permit.

I've been also told that a new passport with no stamps is a very common case. So you shouldn't worry.

Comment: Thank you very much , you are a legend :)